# How do I get data from the Google Analytics API by filtering on a specific URL

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Good afternoon, I'm developing an application in Node.js, this application returns the total views of my projects in JSON.

My question is: how do I get the total views of a specific page or URL. Bearing in mind that this will become an attribute for my function later.

```
async function getTopPosts(customUrl) {  /* I need the Custom URL to be used as a filter */

    try {
        await jwt.authorize();

        const response = await google.analytics("v3").data.ga.get({
            auth: jwt,
            ids: "ga:" + VIEW_ID,
            "start-date": "2019-01-01",
            "end-date": "today",
            dimensions: "ga:pagePath,ga:pageTitle",
            metrics: "ga:pageviews",
            sort: "-ga:pageviews",
            "max-results": "10",
            filters: "ga:medium==organic",
        });

        let data = response.data
        console.log(data)

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

I tried to see the GA-API documentations [GA-API](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/) but I was not successful.

I hope it returns a JSON containing only the total views of a specific page or URL of my Google Analytics project.